# How to size a Cuckoo Filter?

Tags: data-structures

I have a need to use a Cuckoo Filter but I'm not sure how to size it.  I found a calculator for Bloom Filters (https://hur.st/bloomfilter/) for which I can calculate in a few ways.  I can specify the approximate number of items and the desired false positive rate and it will tell me the size and number of hash functions.  I'm looking for something similar for a Cuckoo Filter but I haven't found one or other instructions on how to find those numbers.

I'm looking at a Node or Python implementation.  It seems the parameters to define the filter are:

- filter size or capacity
- bucket size
- fingerprint size

I want to specify the number of elements (eg 100k) and an FPR (eg .1%) to find out the parameters needed.

Comment: The article https://brilliant.org/wiki/cuckoo-filter/ shows you the formula for computing the size, based on the load factor and false positive rate. Some simple algebra should let you solve for any one of those.

Comment: Thank - I had read the article before asking this and it just reread it now and it's still not clear to me what the equation is (maybe I'm just slow..)   If you would like to paste the equation as an answer, I'd be happy to upvote and select as answer if it's right.

Comment: @Yehosef, I was wondering if you found the answer to your question, since I am also looking for the same. It's really difficult to estimate what size (in Bytes) would it require, and none of the documentation online helps

Answer (score 6):

Based on information in the original paper (https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dga/papers/cuckoo-conext2014.pdf), you need to choose bucket size first, which allows you to determine fingerprint size and capacity. Bucket size is based on the desired false positive rate:

> "the space-optimal bucket size depends on the target false positive
>   rate ε: when ε > 0.002, having two entries per bucket yields slightly
>   better results than using four entries per bucket; when ε decreases to
>   0.00001 < ε ≤ 0.002, four entries per bucket minimizes space"<sup>1</sup>

For your suggested 0.1%, that would mean a bucket size of 4.

The fingerprint size depends on bucket size and false positive rate.

> "To retain the target false positive rate ε, the filter ensures 2b/2<sup>f</sup>
>   ≤ ε, thus the minimal fingerprint size required is approximately: f ≥ log<sub>2</sub>(1/ε) + log<sub>2</sub>(2b)"<sup>1</sup>

With b bucket size, an error rate of 0.1% would require ~10 + 3 = 13 bits for a fingerprint.

Finally, capacity is determined by the number of elements divided by the maximum allowable load, which is determined by bucket size.

> "With k = 2 hash functions, the load factor α is 50% when the bucket
>   size b = 1 (i.e., the hash table is directly mapped), but increases to
>   84%, 95% or 98% respectively using bucket size b = 2, 4 or 8."<sup>1</sup>

So 100k / 0.95 gives you a capacity of 106k.

I don't know of any one formula to give you these answers, since they depend on each other, but hopefully each of those steps makes sense.

For 100k elements and 0.1% FPR, that's:

- filter size of 106k
- bucket size of 4
- fingerprint size of 13 bits

<sub><sup>1</sup> Bin Fan, Dave G. Andersen , Michael Kaminsky , Michael D. Mitzenmacher, Cuckoo Filter: Practically Better Than Bloom, Proceedings of the 10th ACM International on Conference on emerging Networking Experiments and Technologies, December 02-05, 2014, Sydney, Australia  [doi>10.1145/2674005.2674994]</sub>

Answer (score 2):

According to https://brilliant.org/wiki/cuckoo-filter/ (scroll down to "Space Complexity"), the number of bits per entry is determined by:

```
bitsPerEntry = (log(1/fpp)+2)/load
```

`fpp` is your False Positive Probability. `load` is how full you want the table to be.

So just figure out how many items you want to put in the table, multiply by the `bitsPerEntry`, and divide by 8. That will tell you how many bytes to allocate for your table. By applying some simple algebra, you can structure the equation to solve for any one of the unknowns.

The article says that with a load of 95.5%, you can maintain a stable false positive rate with 7 bits per entry.

Comment: Hi - thanks for this.  But I'm still not sure how to figure out what numbers to put into the equation to get the variables needed to create the cuckoo filter.  For example: for the implementation at https://www.npmjs.com/package/cuckoo-filter there are variables `size`,`bucket_size`, `fingerprint_size`.  All the implementations I've seen have these settings, sometimes a few more.  If I wanted to have a Cuckoo filter with an `fpp` of  .1% with 100k elements, how can I figure out using this equation (or a different one..) what values to use when making the filter?  Thanks!

Comment: @Yehosef A full explanation of the math is in the original paper: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dga/papers/cuckoo-conext2014.pdf. I'd suggest you read the entire paper, think about it, and then read again. I don't have the time right now to write an explanation of the math. But you can dig it out if you study the paper.

Answer (score -1):

The size of the fingerprint determines your error rate for the most part. As you can see in Figure 3 in the [Cuckoo paper](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dga/papers/cuckoo-conext2014.pdf), the bucket size does not have a major effect on the accuracy. Bucket size can reduce insert time considerably since it reduces the number of relocations of existing fingerprints in occupied buckets.

I would recommend fingerprints 7, 15, 23, 31 etc' which will maximize both accuracy and speed. The reason for (8 * n) - 1 is, one bit is used to tell whether the cell is occupied at all since 0 is legal.

To answer your question, I would recommend

- Capacity - what you need plus 5-10%
- FingerPrint - 15 bits
- Bucket size - 4